# Powerbuilder - Open window from another window

Tags: windows, response, powerbuilder

I want to open a window from another window with only one parameter. My problem is that the window that I want to open is not response type, so it won't open and I get an error. If I change the window type from main to response, it works, but I can't do that. I tried to open it with OpenWithParm. What else can I do?

Thanks!

Comment: Code and error messages would be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OpenSheetWithParm should work for you.

Answer (score 0):

If you can´t use a response window , you can set a global variable in the first window and get it in the open event on second window